# Passing JSON data on JQuery countdown script

Tags: jquery, json, countdown

I have this example output

```
"16:27:22"
```

And I have a JQuery code that gets the string

```
function insertReply(content) {
    document.getElementById('output').outerHTML = content;
}

// create script element
var script = document.createElement('script');
// assing src with callback name
script.src = 'time1.php?callback=insertReply';
// insert script to document and load content
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

And I have that countdown code from Keith Wood's site

```
$('#noDays').countdown({until: *script*, format: 'HMS'});
```

How can I extract the hours, minutes, seconds to work for the `until:` ?
The point of this is to echo the desired time so the JQ will show the countdown.

I'm sorry if that looks simple for you but I was missing in school when the teacher gave us JS lessons :P

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about JSON. Or where is it?

Comment: I think you want to split the time you can use var str = "16:27:22"; str.split(":");

Comment: I actually want to make a live countdown timer of a time value passed from my php to the JQuery via JSON or the insertReply function